# Apache2 adheres to www.example.org rules but not example.org (only on HTTP)

Tags: web-server, virtualhost, apache2

I have an odd issue with Apache and example.org.

Both www.example.org and example.org point to the same IP address.

http://example.org -> Apache Default Page
http://www.example.org -> https://www.example.org

https://example.org redirects to https://www.example.org correctly.

I'm struggling to work out why http://example.org doesn't seem to adhere to vhost rules.

Here's the vHost conf

```
<VirtualHost example.org:80 *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/exampleorg/httpdocs"
    ServerName www.example.org
    ServerAlias example.org
    <Directory "/var/www/example/httpdocs">
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.org [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.org
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.org%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>
```

I've tried

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
<VirtualHost example.org:80 *:80>
<VirtualHost example.org:80>
```

I've tried swapping the ServerName and ServerAlias.

I've tried adding both to ServerAlias.

I've tried with/without the address specified in the hosts file.

I do not want to disable the default page, there are many domains that still resolve to this IP - I do not want them to display example.org content.

I'm running out of things to try.. Can anyone suggest where to poke next?

Answer (score 0):

Simple use Redirect

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
     ServerName example.org 
     ServerAlias www.example.org 
     Redirect / https://example.org/ 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I... don't think you've quite understood the question being asked.